# How to remove the space and plus for this code using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to remove the white space and plus sign, now I am geting `"Individual House"`, I want to pass this value to the next page by AJAX, also some extra things:

`searchProperties?propertyType=%5B%22`**`Individual`**`+`**`House`**`%22%2C%22`**`Row`**`+`**`House`**`%22%5D`

---

I want to pass the AJAX data URL like this:

`searchProperties?propertyType="["Individual House","Row House"]"`

```js
function createJSON() {
  property_type = [];
  $('#property_type:checked').each(function () {
    //property_type.push($(this).val());
    property_type.push(jQuery.trim($(this).val().replace(/\s+/g, ' '))); // ["Individual+House","Row+House"]

  });
  var property_typejson = JSON.stringify(property_type),
      data = {};

  if(property_type != '')
    data['propertyType'] = property_typejson;

  console.log(data);

  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',   
    url: "map.php",
    data: data,
    success: function (data) {
      console.log(data);
    },
    error: function (errMsg) {
      console.log(errMsg);
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" id="property_type" name="property_type[]"
       value="Individual House" /> Individual House
<input type="checkbox" id="property_type" name="property_type[]"
       value="Row House" /> Row House
<input type="checkbox" id="property_type" name="property_type[]"
       value="Villa" /> Villa

<br></br>

<button type="button" onClick="createJSON()">
  <i class="fa fa-search"></i>Update search
</button>
```

Comment: What's your question exactly? What you want to pass is not JSON, since the strings are not quoted.

Comment: My question is while passing(next page) the values, i want to remove the white spaces and % and +

Comment: I don't think you do. `%5B` == `[` That must be encoded because it's a special character in URLs.

Comment: Can u please update your answer

Comment: `+` means space in a URL.  Why not send the data as JSON using a POST request instead?  Also, you should *never* have more than one element with the same ID.  Change `id="property_type"` to `class="property_type"`.

Comment: Why are you using an inline `onClick` attribute when you're using jQuery?  You should set up a click listener instead.

Comment: I need function so i made like this function

Comment: You are making this harder than it needs to be

Comment: How can do, any one update your exact working code

Answer (score 0):

I've changed this considerably:

Added an ID to your button, set up a click listener on it, changed your GET to a POST request, changed your data to legitimate JSON, and wrote up a bit of PHP to read that JSON on the other end.

Also, I've renamed your function to `submitAjax()`, since that seems more logical to me.

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
  $(document).on("click", "#btnSubmitJson", function (e) {
   e.preventDefault(); // don't submit the form normally, we'll handle that with jQuery
   submitAjax();
  });
 });

 function submitAjax() {
  var property_type = [];

  $(".property_type:checked").each(function () {
   property_type.push($(this).val()); // You don't need trim, your values don't start or end with a space, replacing \s with ' ' literally does nothing given your values
  });

  var jsonData = {
   property_type : property_type
  };

  jsonData.another_var = "something else"; //add more stuff to the object


  console.log("jsonData :", jsonData ); // you can console.log out more than one thing, I like to include a label so I know what I'm looking at

  $.ajax({
   type: "POST", 
   url: "map.php",
   data: jsonData,
   success: function (data) {
    console.log("success: ", data);
   },
   error: function (errMsg) {
    console.log("error: ", errMsg);
   }
  });
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" class="property_type" name="property_type[]"
       value="Individual House" /> Individual House
<input type="checkbox" class="property_type" name="property_type[]"
       value="Row House" /> Row House
<input type="checkbox" class="property_type" name="property_type[]"
       value="Villa" /> Villa

<br></br>

<button type="button" id="btnSubmitJson">
  <i class="fa fa-search"></i>Update search
</button>
```

PHP:

```
$submittedJson = $_POST['jsonData'];

print_r($submittedJson);
```

Comment: I tried your code as GET method but that also not getting ,map.php?another_var=something%20else

Comment: Why do you want to use GET?

Answer (score 0):

HTML:  IDs in html objects are required to be unique so I updated your html:

```
               <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
                <!-- your ids should be -->
                <input type="checkbox" id="IndividualHouse" name="property_type[]"
                       value="Individual House" /> Individual House
                <input type="checkbox" id="RowHouse" name="property_type[]"
                       value="Row House" /> Row House
                <input type="checkbox" id="Villa" name="property_type[]"
                       value="Villa" /> Villa

                <br></br>

                <button type="button"  id="btnUpdateSearch">
                    <i class="fa fa-search"></i>Update search
                </button>
```

then simplified the JavaScript to take advantage of the ids.

```
                    $(function ($) {
                        $("#btnUpdateSearch").click(function () {
                            $chk = $("input:checked");
                            var arr = [];
                            $chk.each(function () { arr.push(this.id); })

                            var data = { 'propertyType': JSON.stringify(arr) };

                            $.ajax({
                                type: 'GET',
                                url: "map.php",
                                data: data,
                                success: function (data) {
                                    console.log(data);
                                },
                                error: function (errMsg) {
                                    console.log(errMsg);
                                }
                            });
                        });

                    });

                </script>
```

Comment: My Question After checked value i want to pass in another page,while passing for me it will taking white spaces and %  like passing map.php?propertyType=%5B%22IndividualHouse%22%2C%22RowHouse%22%5D

Comment: But my case don't want like this , map.php?propertyType=["Individual House." RowHouse"]"

Comment: But my case don't want like this , map.php?propertyType="["Individual House,"RowHouse"]"

Comment: map.php?propertyType=["Individual House." RowHouse"]"  is not valid.  If you want it done this way, you will need to stringify then url encode and reverse at the other end. I guess I still don't fully understand what you are trying to do.